# flipping a number using Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

My instructions: Write a program that reads an integer (greater than 0 and less than 1000) from the console and flip digits of the number, using the arithmetic operators / and %. The result of the flip operation should always be a three-digit number. Make sure that your program works for one, two, and three-digit inputs
My issue: i can't get my code to work with the umber 32 or 120.

```
num = int(input())
flip = 0 
reverse = 0

while 9 > num > 0:
    num = num * 10
    flip = num
while (num == 10): 
    num = num * 10 
    flip = num
while 100 > num > 10:
    flip = flip + num % 10
    num = num // 10
    flip = flip * 10

while num > 100:
    flip = flip * 10
    flip = flip + num % 10
    num = num // 10
    flip = flip * 10
    flip = flip + num % 10
    flip = flip * 10
    num = num // 10
    flip = flip + num % 10
print(flip)
```

Comment: Could you provide use cases for input and desired output please?

Comment: It always prints "two answers" because your print statement is inside your while loop. Instead, save your answer as a variable while you compute it and print that variable at the very end of your program.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand it correctly but this should always print 3 digit number (given that input is less than 1000 and is positive integer).

```
result = ""

num = int(input())

for i in range(3):
    result += "{}".format(num%10)
    num = num // 10

print (result)
```

Answer (score 0):

num (n1, n2, n3 ... nk)
->
ret (nk, nk-1, ...  n1)

just multiply 10 from low

```
ret = 0

num = int(input())

while num > 0:
    ret = ret * 10
    ret = ret + num % 10
    num = num // 10

print (ret)
# 1003 -> 3001
```

Comment: Don't know why this answer was voted down. **This works for _any_ positive integer** which Python accepts; and only uses the floor division and modulo operators; _no string operations_. (The `while` loop could be shortened to these two lines `ret = ret * 10 + num % 10` & `num //= 10`.)

Comment: Hello! that you so much it actually kind of worked! I understood the logic you were using, so I tried to apply it to my code, but I'm having trouble when the input is 32 or 120.

Comment: This is my code                           num = int(input())
flip = 0 
reverse = 0

while 9 > num > 0:
    num = num * 10
    flip = num
while (num == 10): 
    num = num * 10 
    flip = num
while 100 > num > 10:
    flip = flip + num % 10
    num = num // 10
    flip = flip * 10

while num > 100:
    flip = flip * 10
    flip = flip + num % 10
    num = num // 10
    flip = flip * 10
    flip = flip + num % 10
    flip = flip * 10
    num = num // 10
    flip = flip + num % 10
print(flip)

Comment: @KathyADuarte Why do you have so many different while loops? You would either a) use the one while loop as shown in both answers so far or b) use `if` statements for each condition of num you're checking (eg `9 > num > 0`) or c) The while loops should start at the largest test (`num > 100`) and works its way down. But none of these are necessary and it works with just the one loop. Btw, what are your expected flip values for 32 and 120?